# get user info from facebook page visitor post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I tried to use
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/visitor_posts
for getting vistor posts.
However, i get only this info

`"data": [
    {
      "created_time": "2018-03-19T12:03:09+0000",
      "message": "test message 1.",
      "id": "213650785430758_1465685383560629"
    },
    {
      "created_time": "2018-03-19T10:35:52+0000",
      "message": "test message 2",
      "id": "213620785430758_1465624200233424"
    }
]`

however i need infomation like who posted the posts. I tried to use 'from' field, but that is also not working. Please help me how to get the user info. Thanks.

Comment: You need to use a page access token for the page the post is on. If you don’t have that, then this info is simply not available any more to you.

Comment: I had page access token and used that while making API call

Comment: And did you also ask for the fields? // Just tested it, to be sure - works _fine_ with a page access token belonging to the page the post is on.